# In the "$S \cup \{s\}$"-structure induced by expanding $S$, what is $s^A$?

Tags: logic, computer-science, model-theory

On  [p127](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA127)  in *§3.  Extensions by Definitions* in *VIII  Syntactic Interpretations and  Normal Forms* In Ebbinghaus' *Mathematical Logic*: $S$ is a (non-logical) symbol set

> Let $S$  be given, and let $s$ be a relation symbol, a function symbol or a con-
> stant with $s \notin S$. Furthermore, let $\Phi \subset L_0^S$ and let $\delta_s$  be an $S$-definition of $s$ in $\Phi$.  We define, in the obvious way, the associated syntactic interpretation $I$ of $S' := S \cup \{s\}$  in $S$  to be the identity on the symbols from  $S$ and
>
> $$ (I(S') =)\phi_{S'}(v_0)  := v_0  ==  v_0, \quad I(s)  := \phi_s $$
>
> (where $\phi_s$  is as in Definition 3.1 on [p126](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA126)).  So $\Phi_I$ (If I am correct $\Phi_I$ is induced from $I$ but not from $\Phi$, c.f. [p120](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA120)) is logically equivalent to
>
> - the empty set of sentences, if $s$  is a relation symbol,
> - $\{\forall v_0, ... \forall v_{n-1} \exists^{=1} v_n \phi_f( v_0, ... ,v_{n-1}, v_n)\}$, if  $s$  is  an $n$-ary function symbol $f$,
> - $\{\exists^{=1} v_0 \phi_c(v_0)\}$,  if $s$  is a constant $c$.
>
> Therefore, we have for  every $S$-structure $\mathfrak{A}$ with $\mathfrak{A} \models \Phi$:
>
> (*)  $\mathfrak{A} \models \Phi_I$
>
> (**)  $(\mathfrak{A}, s^A) \models \Phi$  iff  $\mathfrak{A}^{-I} = (\mathfrak{A}, s^A) $.

- If I am correct, $\Phi$ and $\delta_s$ induce $I$, and then $I$ induces $\Phi_I$. What relation and difference are between $\Phi$ and $\Phi_I$, both of which are sets of $S$-sentences? Does (*) show a relation between the two?
- In (**), what does $s^A$ mean? What is $A$ ? (I guess that because $\mathfrak{A}^{-I} |_S = \mathfrak{A}$ (c.f. [p121](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA121)), $s^A$ may mean $I(s)$, but I am not sure what $A$ and $s^A$ mean.  I doubt $A$ is the domain of a structure, specifically $I$, because $I$ is a syntactic interpretation, which [I am not sure is an interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795345/what-is-the-difference-and-relation-between-interpretation-and-syntactic-interpr) (and therefore has a domain), and whose domain if it has one is unclear to me and at least not chosen as some $$ on [p120](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA120). )

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the interpretation (pg. 28). $A$ is the underlying set and sometimes it’s identified with the whole structure, like how we refer to a group $G$ (which should include its composition function, plus inverse and identity by some definitions) but also use that as the underlying set too, such as when one writes “$g\in G$“.

On pg 29, $s^A$ is another way of writing $a(s)$, where $a$ is the mapping in a structure.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What does $s^A$ mean? (2) $I$ is a syntactic interpretation, whose domain is unclear to me (see the other question linked later) and at least not chosen as some $A$ on p120. (3) Do you assume $I$ is an interpretation?  [Is a syntactic interpretation also an interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795345/what-is-the-difference-and-relation-between-interpretation-and-syntactic-interpr)

Comment: (1) It is the interpretation, in the usual sense (not syntactic): you send the symbol to some actual "thing" in the model. In this case, $s$ is defined by a first order formula in terms of the original symbol set $S$ and so you extend the interpretation to the language enriched by $s$ by sending $s$ to whatever that definition picks out (2,3) Sound like they have more to do with your other question, and I think outside the scope of this one. The syntactic interpretation is not an interpretation in the usual sense. It and its domain are defined a little earlier in this chapter.

Comment: In (very very) brief the syntactic interpretation is a rule for translating one language into another. A really silly example: multiplicative group notation and additive group notation for abelian groups are distinguished from each other if you write one with $*$ and one with $+$, but you can define a syntactic interpretation of one in the other by replacing all the $*$'s with $+$'s (and vice versa). A little less trivial might be something like interpreting "groups with a squaring function" into groups (because there is a plain group formula which picks out the squaring function).

Comment: What is $A$ in $s^A$ then? How does $s^A$ mean "  is defined by a first order formula in terms of the original symbol set  "?

Comment: The $A$ is just the model that's being talked about. A syntactic interpretation boils down to defining new symbols in terms of the old ones and then interpreting the new symbols according to those definitions. $s^A$ is simply the interpretation of $s$ as the value that $s$ is defined to take. You may want to revisit the start of the chapter, and especially the examples which are probably better than mine.